# Aggregate a RANGE of values using R language

Tags: r, csv, range, aggregate

I have a CSV file having more than 2000rows with 8 columns. The schema of the csv is as follows.

```
col0   col1  col2 col3......
1.77   9.1   9.2  8.8
2.34   6.3   0.9  0.44
5.34   6.3   0.9  0.44
9.34   6.3   0.9  0.44........
.
.
.
2000rows with data as above
```

I am trying to aggregate specific sets of rows(set1: rows1-76, set2:rows96-121..) from the above csv e.g between 1.77 to 9.34 and for all the columns for their corresponding rows- the aggregate of these rows would be one row in my output file. I have tried various methods but i could do it for only a single set in the csv file.

The output would be a csv file having aggregate values of the specified intervals like follows.

```
col0  col1  col2  col3
3.25   8.2   4.4   3.3  //(aggregate of rows 1-3)
2.2    3.3   9.9   1.2  //(aggregate of rows 6-10) 
and so on..
```

Comment: Aggregate using what function? Could you please supply a small example indicating what sort of thing you have *and* what results you expect? If you could show us anything you've tried, that would also greatly help us figure out what you're after.

Comment: Do you have a column marking which `set` each row belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

Considering what Manetheran points out, you should, if not already done, add a column showing which row belongs to which set.

The data.table-way:

```
require(data.table)

set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(col1=rnorm(100),col2=rnorm(100),new=rep(c(1,2),each=50))

dt[,lapply(.SD,mean),by="new"]

   new       col1        col2
1:   1 0.03440355 -0.25390043
2:   2 0.14640827  0.03880684
```

You can replace `mean` with any other "aggregate-function"

Comment: then use write.csv().

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible approach using the base packages:

```
# Arguments:
# - a data.frame
# - a list of row ranges passes as list 
#   of vectors=[startRowIndex,endRowIndex]
#   used to split the data.frame into sub-data.frames
# - a function that takes a sub-data.frame and returns 
#   the aggregated result
aggregateRanges <- function(DF,ranges,FUN){
  l <- lapply(ranges,function(x){ 
    return(FUN(DF[x[1]:x[2],]))
  }
  )
  return(do.call(rbind.data.frame,l))
}

# example data
data <- read.table(
  header=TRUE,
  text=
    "col0   col1  col2 col3
  1.77   9.1   9.2  8.8
  2.34   6.3   0.9  0.44
  5.34   6.3   0.9  0.44
  9.34   6.3   0.9  0.44
  7.32   4.5   0.3  0.42
  3.77   2.3   0.8  0.13
  2.51   1.4   0.7  0.21
  5.44   5.7   0.7  0.18
  1.12   6.1   0.6  0.34")

# e.g. aggregate by summing sub-data.frames rows
result <- 
aggregateRanges(
  data,
  ranges=list(c(1,3),c(4,7),c(8,9)),
  FUN=function(dfSubset) { 
    rowsum.data.frame(dfSubset,group=rep.int(1,nrow(dfSubset)))
  }
)


> result
    col0 col1 col2 col3
1   9.45 21.7 11.0 9.68
11 22.94 14.5  2.7 1.20
12  6.56 11.8  1.3 0.52
```